# How to typedef a pointer to method which returns a pointer the method?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

Basically I have the following class:

```
class StateMachine {
...
StateMethod stateA();
StateMethod stateB();
...
};
```

The methods stateA() and stateB() should be able return pointers to stateA() and stateB().
How to typedef the StateMethod?

Comment: Wow, this problem is much, much harder than meets the eye, in my view. There are all sorts of ways to solve it if you're willing to break full type-safety, but otherwise...wow.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[GotW #57](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/057.htm) says to use a proxy class with an implicit conversion for this very purpose.

```
struct StateMethod;
typedef StateMethod (StateMachine:: *FuncPtr)(); 
struct StateMethod
{
  StateMethod( FuncPtr pp ) : p( pp ) { }
  operator FuncPtr() { return p; }
  FuncPtr p;
};

class StateMachine {
  StateMethod stateA();
  StateMethod stateB();
};

int main()
{
  StateMachine *fsm = new StateMachine();
  FuncPtr a = fsm->stateA();  // natural usage syntax
  return 0;
}    

StateMethod StateMachine::stateA
{
  return stateA; // natural return syntax
}

StateMethod StateMachine::stateB
{
  return stateB;
}
```

> This solution has three main
>   strengths:
>
> 1. It solves the problem as required. Better still, it's type-safe and
>      portable.
> 2. Its machinery is transparent: You get natural syntax for the
>      caller/user, and natural syntax for
>      the function's own "return stateA;"
>      statement.
> 3. It probably has zero overhead: On modern compilers, the proxy class,
>      with its storage and functions, should
>      inline and optimize away to nothing.

Comment: Can't cast Member function pointers to regular function pointers, but otherwise cool. I should point out that you are still just sugaring the cast :).

Comment: I haven't done any C++ development for 5 years, and have gladly forgotten about member function pointers.

Yes, I agree that it is just sugar for the cast in your answer :)

Comment: If you change the typedef it should be okay though right? typedef StateMethod (StateMachine:: *FuncPtr)();

Comment: Ah, that's the syntax I was reaching for. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Using just typedef:

```
class StateMachine {  

 public:  

  class StateMethod;     
  typedef StateMethod (StateMachine::*statemethod)();   

  class StateMethod {  

    statemethod   method; 
    StateMachine& obj; 

   public:  

    StateMethod(statemethod method_, StateMachine *obj_)  
      : method(method_), obj(*obj_) {} 

    StateMethod operator()() { return (obj.*(method))(); }  
  };  

  StateMethod stateA()  { return StateMethod(&StateMachine::stateA, this); }  

  StateMethod stateB()  { return StateMethod(&StateMachine::stateB, this); }  

};
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: njsf proved me wrong here. You might find static casting simpler to maintain, however, so I will leave the rest here.

<strike>There is no 'correct' static type</strike> since the full type is recursive:

```
typedef StateMethod (StateMachine::*StateMethod)();
```

Your best bet is to use `typedef void (StateMachine::*StateMethod)();` then do the ugly `state = (StateMethod)(this->*state)();`

PS: `boost::function` requires an explicit return type, at least from my reading of the [docs](http://synopsis.fresco.org/boost/Scopes/boost/function0.html): `boost::function0<ReturnType>`

Comment: Yeah, that's a "break type-safety" approach as I mentioned in the question comments. It's too bad, really. I do wish there's a way to solve this cleanly. Maybe C++0x will provide a way?

Comment: No, this is actually *impossible* with an eagerly evaluated type system - not just C++'s. You would need a lazly evaluated type system.

Answer (score 2):

My philosophy is don't use raw member function pointers. I don't even really know how to do what you want using raw pointer typedef's the syntax is so horrible. I like using boost::function.

This is <strike>almost</strike> certainly wrong:

```
class X
{
  public:
    typedef const boost::function0<Method> Method;

    // some kind of mutually recursive state machine
    Method stateA()
    { return boost::bind(&X::stateB, this); }
    Method stateB()
    { return boost::bind(&X::stateA, this); }
};
```

This problem is definitely a lot harder than first meets the eye

Comment: Heh, I saw your earlier answer. This is probably the best compromise there is; I was discussing this on IRC and have come to conclude that a typedef referring to itself is probably a "too hard" problem.

Comment: Though, in the inner boost::function0, don't you have to provide a return type, and have that recurse again?

Comment: Could be, I'm not sitting at a compiler

Comment: This sounds like the perfect job for a Y combinator written in the template metaprogramming language

Comment: @1800 INFORMATION: yeah, my first thought was "well, I'll just write a Y Combinator up on typedefs... oh boy. :("

Answer (score 0):

I can never remember the horrible C++ function declspec, so whenever I have to find out the syntax that describes a member function, for example, I just induce an intentional compiler error which usually displays the correct syntax for me.

So given:

```
class StateMachine { 
    bool stateA(int someArg); 
};
```

What's the syntax for stateA's typedef? No idea.. so let's try to assign to it something unrelated and see what the compiler says:

```
char c = StateMachine::stateA
```

Compiler says:

```
error: a value of type "bool (StateMachine::*)(int)" cannot be used to initialize 
       an entity of type "char"
```

There it is: "bool (StateMachine::*)(int)" is our typedef.